# I want to externalize the template to be able to re-use the function in different pages

Tags: javascript

I want to externalize the template to be able to re-use the function in different pages. the content of the page I want to put in the modal window. i want get the content of an external page with javascript.

```js
var establisment1 = [];
establisment1["name"] = "Est 1";
establisment1["type"] = "Clinic";
establisment1["adress"] = "aaaaa";
establisment1["PostalCode"] = "95000";
establisment1["Town"] = "paris";
establisment1["CreationDate"] = "2001";
establisment1["ChangesetDate"] = "2010";

var establisment2 = [];
establisment2["name"] = "Est 2";
establisment2["type"] = "Pharma";
establisment2["adress"] = "bbbbb";
establisment2["PostalCode"] = "91000";
establisment2["Town"] = "lyon";
establisment2["CreationDate"] = "2000";
establisment2["ChangesetDate"] = "2008";

var establisment3 = [];
establisment3["name"] = "Est 3";
establisment3["type"] = "ABC";
establisment3["adress"] = "ccccc";
establisment3["PostalCode"] = "70000";
establisment3["Town"] = "lille";
establisment3["CreationDate"] = "1990";
establisment3["ChangesetDate"] = "2001";

var establisment4 = [];
establisment4["name"] = "Est 4";
establisment4["type"] = "absd";
establisment4["adress"] = "ddddd";
establisment4["PostalCode"] = "80000";
establisment4["Town"] = "lille";
establisment4["CreationDate"] = "1980";
establisment4["ChangesetDate"] = "2016";

var establishments = [establisment1, establisment2, establisment3,establisment4];   
      
    function openModal(id) {
      fillData(id);
      showDialog();
    }
    
  
   function fillData(id) {
      establisment = establishments[id];
      
      var string = document.getElementById("rendertableTemplate").innerHTML;
      var replacedString1 = string.replace("$EstablishmentName", establisment["name"]);
      var replacedString2 = replacedString1.replace("$EstablishmentType", establisment["type"]);
   var replacedString3 = replacedString2.replace("$EstablishmentAdress", establisment["adress"]);
   var replacedString4 = replacedString3.replace("$EstablishmentPostalCode", establisment["PostalCode"]);
   var replacedString5 = replacedString4.replace("$EstablishmentTown", establisment["Town"]);
   var replacedString6 = replacedString5.replace("$EstablishmentCreationDate", establisment["CreationDate"]);
   var replacedString7 = replacedString6.replace("$EstablishmentChangesetDate", establisment["ChangesetDate"]);
 
      document.getElementById("rendertable").innerHTML = replacedString2;
      document.getElementById("rendertable").innerHTML = replacedString3;
   document.getElementById("rendertable").innerHTML = replacedString4;
   document.getElementById("rendertable").innerHTML = replacedString5;
   document.getElementById("rendertable").innerHTML = replacedString6;
   document.getElementById("rendertable").innerHTML = replacedString7;   
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="test2 - Copy.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Establishments</h1>

<div class="container">

  <!-- Trigger the modal -->
  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
   <thead>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>Town</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr><td><a onclick="openModal(0);" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-backdrop="true">company 1</a></td>
      <td><a onclick="openModal(0);" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-backdrop="true">country 1</a></td></tr>
    
  <tr><td><a onclick="openModal(1);" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-backdrop="true">company 2</a></td>
      <td><a onclick="openModal(1);" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-backdrop="true">country 2</a></td></tr>
   
  <tr><td><a onclick="openModal(2);" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-backdrop="true">company 3</a></td>
      <td><a onclick="openModal(2);" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-backdrop="true">country 3</a></td></tr>
  
  <tr><td><a onclick="openModal(3);" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-backdrop="true">company 4</a></td>
      <td><a onclick="openModal(3);" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-backdrop="true">country 4</a></td></tr>
 </tbody>  
 </table>
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">X</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Establishment</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="rendertable">
    <tbody>
     <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td><p>$EstablishmentName</p></td>
     </tr>
  
     <tr>
       <td>EstablishmentType</td>
       <td><p>$EstablishmentType</p></td>
     </tr>
  
  <tr>
        <td>Address</td>
        <td><p>$EstablishmentAdress</p></td>
     </tr>
  
  <tr>
        <td>PostalCode</td>
        <td><p>$EstablishmentPostalCode</p></td>
     </tr>
  
  <tr>
        <td>Town</td>
        <td><p>$EstablishmentTown</p></td>
     </tr>
  
  <tr>
        <td>CreationDate</td>
        <td><p>$EstablishmentCreationDate</p></td>
     </tr>
  
  <tr>
        <td>ChangesetDate</td>
        <td><p>$EstablishmentChangesetDate</p></td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
   </table>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div> 
</table>

       <!--modal template-->
   <div class="modal">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
          <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="rendertableTemplate">
    <tbody>
     <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td><p>$EstablishmentName</p></td>
     </tr>
  
     <tr>
       <td>EstablishmentType</td>
       <td><p>$EstablishmentType</p></td>
     </tr>
  
  <tr>
        <td>Address</td>
        <td><p>$EstablishmentAdress</p></td>
     </tr>
  
  <tr>
        <td>PostalCode</td>
        <td><p>$EstablishmentPostalCode</p></td>
     </tr>
  
  <tr>
        <td>Town</td>
        <td><p>$EstablishmentTown</p></td>
     </tr>
  
  <tr>
        <td>CreationDate</td>
        <td><p>$EstablishmentCreationDate</p></td>
     </tr>
  
  <tr>
        <td>ChangesetDate</td>
        <td><p>$EstablishmentChangesetDate</p></td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i try with this code put my prblem is what i should put instead of url inside the code??
========================================

function httpGetAsync(url, callback)
{
            var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() { 
            if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200)
            callback(xmlHttp.responseText);
 }
xmlHttp.open("GET",url, true);    xmlHttp.send(null);
}

Comment: i have simple page html inside the page created an modal windows to showdilog on click and build simple template with 4 variabel to chenge the content inside the modal windows.

my question if i want move the template to an external page and call back to my home page how is that possible ??

i need to do that cuz i want to re-use the template in another modal.